# ngFormModal in ionic2 (error ngFormModal is not a native property)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

this is my code,i got error like this EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFormModel' since it isn't a known native property.

html:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="registrationForm">

    <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" ngControl="email" ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Telephone</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="phoneNo" ngControl="phone" ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>


    </form>
```

.ts file:

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
constructor(public _form: FormBuilder){
this.registrationForm = this._form.group({
        "email":["",Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')])]
}
```

app.ts:

```
    import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

    ionicBootstrap(MyApp,[
    provideForms(),
    disableDeprecatedForms()]);

package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.10",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
```

Comment: i am new to ionic ,please help me to rectify this problem. I got error only when i use ngFormModal. FormBuilder,validaters working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES only in the component.ts file. 
Please try out the very neat example given by matheo at the following ionic forum topic.

[ionic 2 form showing error](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-forms-showing-error/59653/3)

Please use the package.json in letter and spirit as given in the above example, and the imports, declarations etc in both the component ts and html files.